bat script behaves different when coming from curl pipe
I have a very simple bat script and I'm trying to execute it directly from curl on a windows 10 machine.
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET ME=%~n0
SET PARENT=%~dp0

set VER=0.1

@echo %DATE% %TIME% - ME %ME% - PARENT %PARENT% - VER %VER%

when I try to execute it like this:
curl https://example.com/test.bat | cmd 

ME and PARENT variables are not evaluated correctly
15/10/2024 14:10:48,54 - ME %~n0 - PARENT %~dp0 - VER 0.1

but if a download the bat and execute it after, it shows the values properly.
15/10/2024 14:11:38,93 - ME test - PARENT C:\Users\sim\Desktop\test\ - VER 0.1

am I missing something?

What do you expect to see? Piping the script to cmd is like typing the commands on the keyboard. cmd cannot know how the file is named on the web server.

yeah, I get it now. I was under the wrong impression that it was using some kind of temp file and that's not the case.
I close the question.
thanks @Bodo !

For me it is not clear what problem you are trying to solve. The question looks like an XY problem. For what purpose do you need these values, why do you have to run the script in these two ways and want to get the same values?

Just try:
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions

set "_ver=0.1"
set "_me=%~n0"
set "_parent=%~dp0"

call echo/%%date%% %%time%% - me %%_me%% - parent %%_parent%% - ver %%_ver%%

endlocal


curl "https://example.com/test.bat" 2>&1 | "ComSpec%" /d /e /v /c

:: or ..
curl --silent "https://example.com/test.bat" 2>&1 | "ComSpec%" /d /e /v /c



your answer is correct, is just in my use case I needed a script name and you don't have that when you pipe into cmd

So, why not: curl -L "https://filesamples.com/samples/code/bat/ascii_to_unicode.bat" >"%temp%\SomeFileName.bat" && "%temp%\SomeFileName.bat"? define you name...

I though it was something related to variable evaluation, but as @Bodo pointed out is just that cmd doesn't execute any file, just receive characters.
to solve the situation I was facing I'll use a bootstrap script that will call the real one.
thanks for your help.

ok, but you won't even try? I posted what I tried... I didn't see any anomalies... but please don't tell that to the Bodo!

your solution worked as expected. it was me making some assumptions about how cmd and piping worked on windows.
